# Qt project for Raspberry Pi only builds under certain directory

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, raspberry-pi3

I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) for building Qt for Raspberry Pi, except that I modified it for version 5.8.  I can build the example projects and my own projects as long as they are somewhere within the `~/raspi/qtbase/` folder, however if I try to build a project outside of this folder, it fails with the linker error:

```
~/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicui18n.so.52: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
```

I'm using the same version of `qmake` in both cases, the only difference is the location of the project.  Can someone explain why the build location matters and how I can get the linker to find the right libraries?

Comment: You did not move Qt itself, right? A Qt installation is not movable since the binaries hardcode the install paths. Also, it's not about using the same "version" of `qmake`: you must use the **same** `qmake`. A Qt installation is synonymous with its `qmake`, so to use a particular Qt installation you must invoke its `qmake`. For example, to build your project you'd do `~/raspi/qtbase/bin/qmake ~/foo/bar/myproject.pro` from a build folder.

Comment: Nope, I did not move anything around after building Qt. I'm also calling qmake exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: I'm stumped. It looks as if the linker was finding some system library when the build succeeds, and silently wouldn't when the build fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.  I will update this thread if I figure it out.  Until a few days ago I didn't know anything about building Qt, so there's a lot to be learned here.